# MVC application throws ObjectDisposedException eventhough I used ToList() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing MVC web application and I've got stucked at one point.

The application throws ObjectDisposedException eventhough I used ToList() method while dbContext was still open. Here is my code:

Data Access Layer:

```
        public List<CompanyCode> SearchCompanyCodes(int? projectId=null)
    {
        IQueryable<sl_CompanyCodes> filtered=dbContext.sl_CompanyCodes;

        if(projectId!=null)
        {
            filtered = filtered.Where(cc => cc.Project_ID == projectId);
        }

        return filtered.ToList();
    }
```

Bussiness logic layer:

```
        public List<CompanyCode> CompanyCodes(int? cc_projectId=null)
    {
        List<CompanyCode> result;

        using(var repository=new E6Repository())
        {
            result=repository.SearchCompanyCodes(projectId:cc_projectId);
        }
        // E6Repository.Dispose calls dbContext.Dispose()

        return result;
    }
```

Controller:

```
        public JsonResult CompanyCodes()
    {
        var logic = new GetDataLogic();

        List<CompanyCode> l = logic.CompanyCodes();

        return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have no idea what to do... When I stop debugger just before return action in controller, I can see well filled list when I type l in immediate window (notice at this point `dbContext` is already disposed).

Interesting thing: if I change ActionResult into view with `IEnumerable<CompanyCode>` as model, response is fine and there is no errors.

Can anyone explain me what's going on?

Comment: What's not shown is how the controller logic works.  By changing to a strong type you are asking MVC Binder to provide a strong type which it does.  So it's the binder that is newing up the type with the values the binder knows.  Is this a first time get or a post?

Comment: Please show code for CompanyCode and its mapping. It may be a lazy loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not created an instance of your EF context. Try this:

```
public List<CompanyCode> SearchCompanyCodes(int? projectId=null)
{
    using (var context = new dbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<sl_CompanyCodes> filtered = from compCodes in dbContext.sl_CompanyCodes
                                               select compCodes;
    }

        if(projectId!=null)
        {
            filtered = filtered.Where(cc => cc.Project_ID == projectId);
        }

    return filtered.ToList();
}
```